# Wrap custom post type - ONLY- in a div

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a custom post type called 'subjects'
I want to wrap all the content inside it in the follwoing div

```
`<div id="link_count">`

content 

`</div>`
```

so that any post in 'subjects' would be automatically wrapped in this div
as I use it for tracking purposes and I have 500 posts and I don't want to it manually

how can I do that? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: more clarification needed to answer?

Comment: sorry I edited the code, can you check it now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (is_singular('subjects')) {

    echo '<div id="link_count">';

    the_content(); 

    echo '</div>';  //end of link_count div

}else{

    the_content();

}
```

If this is just simplified code for the question, but you're going to have more items in and around the_content, you can just wrap 2 of the if statements around the call for the div and end of the div...

```
if (is_singular('subjects'))

    echo '<div id="link_count">';

the_content(); //and whatever else goes here.

if (is_singular('subjects'))

    echo '</div>';  //end of link_count div.
```

In either case you'll want to make sure that the CPT is actually "subjects" and not namespaced when it was created or this won't work.  ie you'll need the right name of the cpt as registered in the if statement.

if you want to add to a functions.php, try this.  It's not tested but should work:

```
function add_content_link_count( $content ) {

if (is_singular('subjects')) { 
     $custom_content = '<div id="link_count">'. $content . '</div>';
    } else {
        $custom_content = $content;
    }
return $custom_content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_content_link_count' );
```

Comment: I see, great answer ^^, where should I put it? in the theme's function.php?

Comment: This would go in your index.php or your single.php.  are you looking to add to your functions.php instead?

Comment: yeah as I don't want to touch wordpress core files because automated updates are enabled so it will be reverted to the original. plus maintaining the code in a child's theme function.php is a  bit easier

Comment: your index and single php files should be in your child theme as copied from your regular theme to avoid just this...  However I put a version in my answer that will work for the functions.php as well.  Let me know.